# .NET Web API model binding prefixed properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a view model and models similar to this

```
public class SupplierViewModel
{
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; } 
    //Select Lists and other non model properties
}
```

And two models

```
public class Supplier
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public Contact PrimaryContact { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> SecondaryContacts { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

But in my view the fields get prefixed with the class name so when I send it to the Web API controller it is in the following form

```
{
    Supplier.Name: "test",
    Supplier.PrimaryContact.Name: "test",
    Supplier.SecondaryContacts: [
        { Name: "test" }
    ]
}
```

When I send it to my controller

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("Suppliers/{idSupplier?}")]
public HttpResponseMessage SuppliersAddOrEdit(Supplier Supplier, int idSupplier = 0)
```

It obviously doesn't deserialize because of the prefixes, currently I'm reformatting it before I send the request like this

```
{
    Name: "test",
    PrimaryContact: {Name: "test"},
    SecondaryContacts: [
        {
            Name: "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

then it binds OK, but I'm pretty sure that when I was sending data to an ActionController it knew even without specifying Bind[(Prefix)] that for example

> PrimaryContact.Name: "test"

Would go into the class PrimaryContact. How do I achieve the same result in a Web API controller?

Edit: Based on Jon Susiak's answer I'd like to clarify further

If instead I use a Controller instead of a ApiController my model as it is would bind just fine sending the data in JSON with prefixes, is there a way to achieve the same thing in an ApiController?

Answer (score 0):

In your view you are initially sending a SupplierViewModel however on the POST of the form you are expecting a Supplier object.

You can do one of two things:

a) Change the POST model to SupplierViewModel

b) Change the initial model to Supplier and put the additional properties and Lists in the ViewBag

Comment: This defeats the whole purpose of the ViewModel, also the PrimaryContact object won't be built in the form of: Supplier.PrimaryContact.Name but I would have to reformat it as I've been doing now. What I want to achieve is this public `ActionResult SuppliersAddOrEdit(Supplier Supplier, int idSupplier = 0)` because this works exactly as I want it to, so there has to be a way to achieve the same results in a Web API controller